# MVC/repository: SoC and double checking

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a blog using MVC repository/service layers pattern.
According to Separation of Concern principles, each layer must do only its tasks. So, in my case checking user permissions to the objects (e.g. to the blog posts) must be implemented inside Service layer (SL).
Does that mean that *anything* that is returned from repository layer (RL) must be checked in SL according to its business rules? Maybe it is so - for the cases when one day the repo is substituted with another repo. For example, if the method GetAllMyPosts() of a new repository improperly returns not only my posts but some other's people, they should be filtered off by SL.
But in this case we have double-checkings: one in the RL which retrieves only my posts and other in the SL which filters any posts but those where user is creator.
What is the correct way to implement that? Where and how should I check permissions? Shold my SL trust to RL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. It is ok to use the Repo layer directly provided there is no inherit business logic in it. So things like lookups, etc can go straight through. (again some purists might argue this)

In your example I would have this:

```
Service.GetAllMyPosts()
Repo.GetAllPostsForUser(userId)
```

So SL determines the current user and calls the repo appropriately.

Comment: OK, i came to the same idea - to trust RL that it will retrieve exactly what it must :) thanks.